# How to add keyword-hightlight feature to 'org.eclipse.ui.examples.rcp.texteditor_3.7.0.src'

Tags: eclipse, editor, highlight, keyword, rcp

I downloaded the source code-'org.eclipse.ui.examples.rcp.texteditor_3.7.0'.And I want to add a new feature that makes the key words highlight based on the source code.How could I make it?
I scanned the source code,but I didn't make the structure and procedure clear.Is there any articles or example for me?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your preferences, then color and change the style. Every IDE has this. Sorry I do not have the exact process, I am currently on a phone. However, it is very easy to find and I am sure someone else will have the exact process.